# What is the meaning of "と" in 「言っておくと」?

Tags: particle-と

I was going through the sentences and explanations of "言っておく" when "言っておくと" caught my eye. It repeatedly showed up as an alternative to "言っておくけど". I think けど here is somewhat like "you know" in English. But as for と I really can't think of any usage that could fit in with the sentence. (Not if/when/quotation, definitely not and/with, and then I am baffled...)

> 言っておく**と**、私明日来ないからね
>
> 言っておく**と**、あいつ俺の妹だからね。
>
> 言っておく**けど**、ロスでは車が必要だよ。

Comment: For anyone who didn't know, 「ロス」 means "L.A." in the last example sentence above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「言っておく**と**、～～～。」

simply means:

> "Just so you know, ~~~."

The 「と」 here is a conjunctive particle used to form a light and casual kind of introduction before stating the main point.

Thus, 「言っておく**と**」 and 「言っておく**けど**」 mean fairly different things from each other in that the latter is used when you want to ***warn or caution*** the listener in advance about something that will be stated only a second after.

「言っておく**けど**」 generally has the nuance of "**I've got to warn/tell you beforehand that ~~~**."

Comment: I guess this usage of と is not the kind you can find in a dictionary, but obtained through something like 語感/ニュアンス？ Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, I saw one more sentence this morning: 外で出てみると、うっすらと雪が積もっていました。I think the と here in the first half of the sentence also means the same thing you mentioned above right?